# Как убить процесс полностью, зная PID дочернего?

Tags: windows, bat, powershell

Некий процесс с помощью команды start порождает следующую картину:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я умею автоматизированно находить PID node.js, но убить мне нужно всех троих. Как это можно сделать средствами bat или powershell?

Comment: Вопрос снят, не знал о параметре /B команды START

Answer (score 0):

Если одной командой убить все дочерние процессы, которые породил родитель процесса 666, то так:

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %a in ('wmic process where "processid=666" get parentprocessid /value^|find/i"="') do wmic process where "parentprocessid=%b" call terminate
```